# Replace JSQMessages input toolbar with yes/no buttons

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQMessages to build a chat-UI based app that talks to a web service. However, I don't want the user to be able to respond with open-ended texts but rather a pre-set number of replies such as "yes" and "no" and "maybe".

How do I override the input toolbar with something like a UIStackView of close-ended text buttons (open to another UI option, too)?

I would prefer not to muck up the source code for the library if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the handy property on inputtoolbar:

```
     self.inputToolbar.isHidden = true
```

And then I just added some buttons programmatically.